# React - Missing data in lifted state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**The goal** - I want to set some local form state based on interaction with three checkboxes (see below).

[image: Check box options]

**The rule** - If two options are selected then the **channel state** should be set to `'multi'` if one option is selected then the **channel state** should be the value of the checkbox that is selected (eg `eml`, `push`, `inapp`).

**The problem:** I am able to successfully update the **channel state** in my local form state. But, when I lift the state up via `props.onGenerateResult(data)`, I find that the **channel state** in the data object is an empty string.

Heres what I have so far...

**State to check status of checkboxes** - Initially they are all set to false

```
const [channel, setChannel] = useState('');
const [channelOptions, setChannelOptions] = useState({
    eml: false,
    push: false,
    inapp: false
});
```

Handler that updates **channelOptions** state using computed property values

```
const channelSelectionChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setChannelOptions((prevState) => {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            [e.target.value]: e.target.checked
        };
    });
};
```

JSX pointing to `channelSelectionChangeHandler()` to run

```
<Checkbox value="eml" onChange={channelSelectionChangeHandler}>Email</Checkbox>
<Checkbox value="push" onChange={channelSelectionChangeHandler}>Push</Checkbox>
<Checkbox value="inapp" onChange={channelSelectionChangeHandler}>Inapp</Checkbox>
```

Submit handler that fires on form submission - Lifts all my form state up (This includes channel) and where I handle conditional checking to set the channel state.

```
const onSubmitFormHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // set channel state here
    for (const props in channelOptions) {
        if (channelOptions[props] === true) {
            selectedChannels.push(props);
        }
    }

    if (selectedChannels.legnth === 1) {
        setChannel(selectedChannels[0]);
    } else {
        setChannel('multi');
    }


    const data = { name, date, channel, content, target, type, frequency, market, city,zone };

    props.onGenerateResult(data);
};
```

Why is this? How should I best approach this so that my channel state also gets lifted up? This could be simple if I used [select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) with multiple option but I prefer to use [input type=checkboxes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp). Additionally, I'm thinking of moving the for in loop and if check into my `channelSelectionChangeHandler()`. Just keep the submission handler lean.

Thanks in advance and hope this all made sense.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: @ChrisG This using React useState hook...

Comment: ? What do you mean? That's it's not a dupe because you're using functional components? Lol, no. Anyway, the quick solution is to simply set a variable like `newChannel` instead, then use that variable twice: `setChannel(newChannel)` and `const data = { ..., channel: newChannel, ...}`

Comment: why do you need this as a state at all? `const data = { ..., channel = selectedChannels.length > 1 ? "multi" : "", ... }`

Comment: @Thomas selected channel is ab oject.

Comment: @Samuel in your example, `channel` is a string, either `"multi"` or `""`. `channelOptions` is an object, and `selectedChannels` is an array; which has a `length` property and the value for `channel` seems to be derived directly from this length. if `length > 1 ? "multi" : ""`. And I don't see any other place where you use the `channel` state, except to build `props.onGenerateResult(data);`. So again, do you need `channel` as a state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @chris-g is correct. Even though your example is using the `useState` hook, the behavior is similar to `setState`: The value of `channel` doesn't change immediately after you call `setChannel`. Instead, react will call your component again and the return value of `useState` will contain the updated value. But this is to late for your callback.

To fix your issue, I would recommend two changes:

1. Since `channel` is only computed based on `channelOptions`, use `useMemo` for `channel` instead of `useState`, :

```js
const [channelOptions, setChannelOptions] = useState({
    eml: false,
    push: false,
    inapp: false
});
const channel = useMemo(() => {
  // Compute the value of channel based on the current value of channelOptions
  return Object.keys(channelOptions).reduce((channel = '', key) => {
    if (channelOptions[key] === true) { 
      return channel === '' ? key : 'multi'
    }
    return channel;
  }, '');
// add channelOptions as dependency so this value gets recomputed when they change
}, [channelOptions])
```

2. Use `useCallback` for `onSubmitFormHandler` and use the new `channel` value returned by `useMemo`:

```js
const onSubmitFormHandler = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = { name, date, channel, content, target, type, frequency, market, city,zone };

    props.onGenerateResult(data);
}, [channel, name, date, content, target, type, frequency, market, city, zone, props.onGenerateResult]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I'm pretty new to React and haven't come across `useMemo` and `useCallback` in my learning yet. But this works really well. My only issue now is when I reset the form I cannot reset the values of the checkboxes back to false. I guess this is because I dont have specific state for the checkboxes?

Comment: How are you resetting it? And did you assign your state correctly to the checkboxes? In your code example, it looks like you are setting `value` of each `Checkbox` to a string instead of the actual state value. Maybe try `<Checkbox value={channelOptions.eml} ...>Email</Checkbox>`?

Comment: I have the following  `<form onReset={onResetFormHandler>`. This will trigger a form reset and state reset whenever the following is clicked - `<Button type="reset">`.  Also recall the values from the checkbox is what gets passed to `channelSelectionChangeHandler()`.  So `<Checkbox value={channelOptions.eml}`  will not work.

Comment: Resolved the issue. I have marked your solution as the best one. Thank for your help!!